# Line Chart is not setting backgroundColor when created dynamically Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Im trying to set multiple datasets in the area chart that will be created dynamically. The datasets are showing in the chart but for some reason, the default background color is not setting for the datasets that where put via my method. Everything else in the method seems to be setting correctly. The Background color is even set correctly in the legend background but it doesn't set on the graph

This is my function

```
function createNewDataset(data, labels) {
    let newDataSet = [];
    newDataSet['label'] = "Test";
    newDataSet['lineTension'] = 0.3;
    newDataSet['backgroundColor'] = "rgba(102,223,56,0.71)";
    newDataSet['borderColor'] = "rgb(114,223,52)";
    newDataSet['pointRadius'] = 3;
    newDataSet['pointBackgroundColor'] = "rgb(91,223,88)";
    newDataSet['pointBorderColor'] = "rgb(93,223,65)";
    newDataSet['pointHoverRadius'] = 3;
    newDataSet['pointHoverBackgroundColor'] = "rgb(89,223,47)";
    newDataSet['pointHoverBorderColor'] = "rgb(125,223,72)";
    newDataSet['pointHitRadius'] = 10;
    newDataSet['pointBorderWidth'] = 2;
    newDataSet['data'] = [0, 10000, 5000, 15000, 100000, 20000, 15000, 25000, 20000, 30000, 25000, 40000];


    return newDataSet;
}
```

And this is the hardcoded creation of the dataset

```
 function createLinechart(){
// Area Chart Example
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myAreaChart");
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {

        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ["2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
            datasets: [
                createNewDataset(),{
                    label: "Civic",
                    lineTension: 0.3,
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(222,43,223,0.25)",
                    borderColor: "rgb(223,40,38)",
                    pointRadius: 3,
                    pointBackgroundColor: "rgb(223,52,49)",
                    pointBorderColor: "rgb(223,82,31)",
                    pointHoverRadius: 3,
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgb(223,40,38)",
                    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgb(223,40,38)",
                    pointHitRadius: 10,
                    pointBorderWidth: 2,
                    data: [0, 10000, 5000, 15000, 10000, 20000, 15000, 25000, 20000, 30000, 25000, 40000],
                },{  label: "Accord",
                    lineTension: 0.6,
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(82,119,223,0.54)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
                    pointRadius: 3,
                    pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
                    pointBorderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
                    pointHoverRadius: 3,
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
                    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(78, 115, 223, 1)",
                    pointHitRadius: 10,
                    pointBorderWidth: 2,
                    data: [0, 10000, 5000, 1000, 10000, 2000, 10000, 20000, 25000, 10000, 25000, 40000],}],
        },
        options: {
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            layout: {
                padding: {
                    left: 10,
                    right: 25,
                    top: 25,
                    bottom: 0
                }
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    time: {
                        unit: 'date'
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false,
                        drawBorder: false
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        maxTicksLimit: 7
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        maxTicksLimit: 5,
                        padding: 10,

                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        color: "rgb(234, 236, 244)",
                        zeroLineColor: "rgb(234, 236, 244)",
                        drawBorder: false,
                        borderDash: [3],
                        zeroLineBorderDash: [2]
                    }
                }],
            },
            legend: {
                display: true
            },
            tooltips: {
                backgroundColor: "rgb(255,255,255)",
                bodyFontColor: "#858796",
                titleMarginBottom: 10,
                titleFontColor: '#6e707e',
                titleFontSize: 14,
                borderColor: '#dddfeb',
                borderWidth: 1,
                xPadding: 15,
                yPadding: 15,
                displayColors: false,
                intersect: false,
                mode: 'index',
                caretPadding: 10,
            }
        }
    });}
```

Here is an image of the chart.
The line that is popping out of the graph should have a green back ground color like shown in the legend.
![Line chart][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNoKB.jpg

EDIT New image with dynamic data. They set everything right except for back ground color again
[Linchart][2]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8lOs.jpg

Comment: The source and image provided are so different that I have trouble believing they correspond; in other words, one or the other has been modified. The source contains no green colors and no arguments for the `data` or `label` parameters. Can you include an image from the exact same state as the source (or vice versa)?

Comment: Yeah i agree. I just updated the image. I just changed the color to show that the background was in fact initializing in the legend but not in the chart background like when you do it with hardcoded value. My method createNewDataset is basically the same as hardcoded value but in an array.

Comment: Seems like a bug from chart js because everything else is initializing correctly. If we use { } instead of array [] the background set correctly. But there is no way to create multiple dataset this way

Comment: Cool thanks, I see the issue clearly now. Yeah that's pretty odd. You might simplify the problem by skipping the `createNewDataset` function and hardcoding the "Test" dataset directly next to the other 2 hardcoded datasets. Try to narrow down the apparent bug: e.g. Can you rule out the possibility that your `createNewDataset` function implementation is the problem (it looks ok to me)? Does the first dataset always fail to render the backgroundColor, even if everything is hardcoded? Does the number of datasets matter? etc.

Comment: The number of datasets doesn't matter. If it's one data set the background color still wont initialize if it's use with my method. I really need this method because my graph are now generating dynamicly when the user ask for a specific stats report. Watch the my second edit. The graph now look like that

Comment: Interesting, so it sounds like your `createNewDataset` function is somehow the source of the problem, although so far I cannot find any fault with it. However, you might simplify the function by making it as similar as possible to the hardcoded data for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the current information it sounds like somehow the problem is specific to data coming from the function, although I don't see anything obviously wrong with the function. So instead I would try focusing on the general debugging strategy of simplifying the problem -- in this case simplifying the function to make it closer to the hardcoded data that is working as expected. I suggest something like this, which is about as simple as possible:

```
function createNewDataset(data, label) {
  return {

    // change to `label: label` once working:
    label: "Test",

    lineTension: 0.3,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(102,223,56,0.71)",
    borderColor: "rgb(114,223,52)",
    pointRadius: 3,
    pointBackgroundColor: "rgb(91,223,88)",
    pointBorderColor: "rgb(93,223,65)",
    pointHoverRadius: 3,
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgb(89,223,47)",
    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgb(125,223,72)",
    pointHitRadius: 10,
    pointBorderWidth: 2,

    // change to `data: data` once working:
    data: [0, 10000, 5000, 15000, 100000, 20000, 15000, 25000, 20000, 30000, 25000, 40000]

  };
}
```

Comment: I tried to do this but the problem is when i try to pass the dataset afterwards. I need a variable that have this structure for all my data. Something along ```datasets:[allMyDataset]``` where allMyDataset will have like 9 dataset all in the ```{data},{data},{data} ``` format or else it doesnt work.I just dont know how to add dynamicly dataset of this format. It's just so weird that everything set correctly except for the background color. Btw Thanks Alot for the help

Comment: same issue, did you get it to work @AlexBéliveau ?